# HP Microserver AMD Raid controller

Tags: raid, windows-server-2012, hp, server-setup, controller

I have a HP N54L Microserver which i have been using successfully with Windows Server 2012. I only have the one hard drive in but want to add another in RAID 1 and then another two much larger drives as their own logical drive.

I have read all the help sites i can but cannot find an answer. I wish to retain the data on drive no. and mirror to drive no. 2. However, after i've changed the bios to allow raid and then entered the RAID configuration utility i seem to encounter an older version. While the manual describes various different ways of setting it up, including a 'build' function (which is exactly what i need) and a 'fast init', I just have a box labeled 'initialization'. The options are None, Full, Fast.

Now i realise the Full and Fast will wipe the drives. If  i use 'None' will this build drive 2 based on drive 1? I believe there could be parity issues from readying elsewhere. How should i go about doing this?

Answers of 'use windows raid', 'get a proper raid controller' etc. are not helpful in this instance. I really want to get it working with the inbuilt AMD raid controller if at all possible.

Many thanks in advance.